# Swift Closure "Type 'Int?' is not optional, value can never be nil"

Tags: swift, closures, option-type

```
class Test {
    var x: Int?

    var TestX: () -> Bool {
        return self.x == nil
    }
}
```

Compiler complains:

> Type 'Int?' is not optional, value can never be nil

Tested this in a playground too, same error. By definition `Int?` is an optional right? Is my syntax wrong? Using Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3

**EDIT**:

This works

```
class Test {
    var x: Int?

    var TestX: () -> Bool { return
        { () in
            self.x == nil
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Should it be `var TestX: Bool` instead of `var TestX: () -> Bool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the answers assumed I wanted to return a Bool but I specifically wanted to return a Closure that returns a Bool (passing the closure as a function argument) . Anyway I figured out how to do it, was a syntax issue. Though still not sure on what the syntax means but anyway. Here's the solution:

```
class Test {
    var x: Int?

    var TestX: () -> Bool { return
        { () in
            self.x == nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no parameters to your closure, you can simply use two brackets:

```
class Test {
  var x: Int?
  var TestX: () -> Bool { return { x == nil } }
}
```

No need for the self as well.